# Finding device ID from kernel thread

Tags: cuda

On a node with several GPUs, GPUs are assigned a unique id from 0 upwards to distinguish them. In CUDA, is there a way for a thread in the kernel code running on the GPU to know what the id of the device it's executing on is?

Currently I am doing this by passing each GPU an int into it's constant memory but I figured there might be a cleaner way to complete this simple task such as a builtin function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your device supports cuda dynamic parallelism, you can use the `cudaGetDevice()` call in device code as documented [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#api-reference):

> `cudaGetDevice`    Always returns current device ID as would be seen from host

Comment: It's not as nice as I would have hoped but it seems like the only alternative to my method so I'll accept the answer, it's nice to know.